# Why one languages can work with cross domain requests better than another ones

Tags: javascript, cors, cross-domain

I have noticed that sometimes it is difficult or even impossible to make some cross domain requests through jquery.ajax but is very easy with some Java libraries like OkHttpClient. And also some cross domain requests may result with 200 http code in php and get message that "Allow access origin" header is not present in other languages. Is that specific properties of certain language or what?

Comment: It's specific to the browser. Cross domain policy is something the browser enforces, nothing to do with the language as such. Java (typically, these days) does not run in the browser and can send http requests wherever it wants.

Comment: These are **libraries**, not languages. I think I can probably design a library for any language that will make your cross-domain requests as hard as writing a Brainfuck program, or program for any other esoteric language of your choice.

Comment: Thanks! That makes it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS or Cross Origin Resource Sharing prevents http requests from other domains, it's a browser technology so if you attempt to perform an ajax http request it will fail while one from java wont.

Read about CORS here:
[HTTP Access Control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)